# Unusual responsive split slider with preview

Tags: javascript, css, layout, slider, responsive-design

I've looked at loads of different sliders and haven't found anything that accomplishes what the designer would like. The image below should help explain. Note that there is space above and below the slider for header/footer content.

A. Basically the idea is for the next image (2) to be partially visible on the right using a certain amount of screen space, say 10%.

B. The current image (1) floats to the left and fills the height - it may be a wide or narrow image.

C. The amount of space shown in light gray will depend on the user's available screen space. When the images reach full resolution, then the gap will expand as needed.

D. In reverse, as the available space shrinks the gap will shrink, and

E. After the gap has reached a minimum size, the slides shrink.

F. Then the current slide (1) will start to be clipped from the left & right if needed (wide images).

G. For the animation, the next slide (2), slides over to fill the gap and then bumps the current slide (1) out, leaving a gap before pulling the next image partially in.

Is there a slider that already does something similar, or do I need to modify an existing one? If so, what would be a good starting point? I've tried ones like Flexslider, but the JS resizing interferes with getting two on the screen.

No image posting privs yet, so here it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0qyS.jpg

Comment: Hmmm... perhaps this one is a bit difficult.

Comment: Dang, over a month and no comments. Looks like this is too tough for SO folks. Good thing I quoted high for the client, since it looks like I'll be building from scratch. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one out....

[Cool carousel](http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/44/)

Check out the examples given more on the Site....it might help out your Query. 
here's another one
http://jsfiddle.net/JCQ6Q/15/ 
All the best. 
Vote up if it helps you. :)

Comment: Well found, it certainly looks like a good foundation to work from. Especially with the onBefore/onAfter/onCreate! Thanks. Now to figure out the best way to do the "slide and push" effect.

Comment: i have edited the answer...given a new link...check it out...it might help you